# Node modules dependency issue

Tags: python, node.js, visual-c++, npm-install, node-gyp

When installing a package (in **windows 8.1**) via NPM some module had a dependency that fired node-gyp rebuild which spawns tons of errors:

**Error**

[image]

I don't know what to do to resolve this error. I search a lot but I could not understand anything.
Which things I need to install for this PYTHON or some visual libraries

Answer (score 0):

yep, you need to install `node-gyp` and its dependencies. See the installation guide on their repo: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp